# Laravel cron not reading in correct env variables in elastic beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a cronjob.config file (ebextensions), this gets deployed on the Elastic Beanstalk but when I check the logs I get errors such as connection refused the reason seems to be because the cron is trying to read in the env file within /var/app/current/ instead of reading /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env can anyone help resolve (nb all vars are set in the environment properties and the application works fine except for the cron)? secondly a lot of examples use /var/www/html/artisan instead of /var/app/current/artisan can anyone advise what is correct (and why)?

Here is the code:

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/schedule_run":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            * * * * * root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && /usr/bin/php /var/app/current/artisan schedule:run 1>> /var/log/eb-cron.log 2>&1

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

Thanks in advance....

I tried removing all db env vars from the .env file hoping that the cron job would pick up the values from ebs environment properties but no joy

Comment: I am confused... why are you using `/var/app/current/artisan`? What do you have in there? `/var/www/html/artisan` is usually a default installation path, but not a MUST path, it is wherever your laravel is installed. Also, I think you should be able to run `/usr/bin/php /var/app/current/artisan schedule:run --env=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env` and that should work, but I can be totally mistaken (I do not have a terminal on this machine)